# How to disable Google Chrome source compression "?body=1"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug some JavaScript for a Rails project and its incredibly frustrating to go line by line when the source code is compressed in the Sources developer tab.

I know this compression is done by Chrome through the `body` variable. What I want to know is if there is any way to stop Chrome from compressing files in source view, i.e:

`\application.js?body=1` --> `\application.js`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Compression is being done by Rails. Disable it in your configuration:

```
# config/production.rb (or whatever environment you're in)
config.assets.compress = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate a new feature in Chrome called *Source Maps*.

Source Maps allows Chrome to map the compressed source code it receives to the uncompressed original, which in turn means that you can debug the code, even though it's been compressed.

This feature should help you get around this kind of problem without having to change the compression settings on your server.

You can read more about it here: http://blog.mascaraengine.com/news/2012/4/16/sourcemap-support-in-chrome-greatly-improves-debugging.html

I believe this feature is still in test and not yet in the final release version of Chrome. I'm sure it will arrive in due course, but for the time being you may need to install the "Canary" version of Chrome, ie the pre-release version that includes all the forthcoming features that they're still working on.